# OpenCart 1.5: how to disable caching for SVG?

Tags: svg, opencart

I think to use svg for images of brands - svg is responsive and good for displays with high DPI. But I have problem with caching mechanism of Opencart 1.5 than can't correct cache vector images and in browser I not see image.

I not found (in search) any solution for this or any extension for Opencart - svg can be minified too, but this is not raster.

I am not expert for Opencart and php and I ask you about better sulution in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the image resize function to skip images that have the `svg` file extension with a slight mod.  Check in `catalog/model/tool/image.php` for the line:

```
if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
```

and include some logic to skip files with "svg" extension:

```
if (strtolower($extension) != 'svg' && ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height)) {
```

The result will be that an unmodified copy of the original is placed in the `image/cache` directory and used instead of processing with GD library.

Answer (score 0):

As a [possible purpose for uploading SVG seems to not be planned](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/3064) into the `2.0.x` serie of OpenCart, I suppose there's no solution *at this time* for the former `1.5.x` serie.